# glew32.dll missing from computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm building an engine from scratch, and it's going for the most part, going great, until I ran into an error. Which is glew32.dll is missing from your computer. I've tried to put the dll into a folder and include that into Visual studio 2013, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think including the directory of the dll will do; you have to put the dll in the folder where the executable will run or put it in system32/sysWOW64

Comment: I don't have that folder. I put the dll into my project directory but then I get the error 0xc000007b

Comment: "I don't have that folder" Yes you do. It's in C:\Windows\.

But anyway, are you sure your executable runs from your project directory? It might be set to run in a sub-folder, or another folder entirely

Comment: Mate, I don't have a sysWOW64 folder...

Comment: Of course you might not have the sysWOW64 folder since it only applies to 64 bits Windows (ironically, that folder is for 32 bits dlls, not 64 bits ones).

system32 does the same thing for 32 bits Windows

Comment: I have a 64 bit system???

Comment: Why don't I have the folder?

Comment: So, I found it, it wasn't in my system32 folder...

Comment: Still the same error?

Comment: You should put this as an answer then accept your own answer

Answer (score -1):

*Solution by OP*

To fix it, add STATIC_GLEW to your pre-processing in properties/ C/C++